# Как в React сделать перенос?

Tags: reactjs, строки, текст

Как в компоненте React.ReactNode сделать перенос строки? \n не помогает

Comment: `<br />` ? Или что ты имел ввиду?

Comment: @EugeneX неа, не помогает

Comment: Давай ты кусочек кода дашь посмотреть, и тебе с радостью помогут. А то вообще не ясно что ты имеешь ввиду.

Comment: Есть ещё старый хак {"\n"} отрисовать \n как JS строку.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Долго искал ответ. Вот он: `<React.Fragment><br/><React.Fragment>`

Answer (score 1):

В строке `\n`, а в стилях `white-space: pre-wrap`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const Example = () => {
  const output = 'First line\n\Second line';

  return (
    <h1 style={
      { 
        whiteSpace: 'pre-line',
      }
    }>
      {output}
    </h1>);
};

export default Example;
```